# Редактирование сортировки Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Нужно отредактировать сортировку p.price что бы она выводила значение price + price_option, либо каким-то другим способом настроить сортировку(цена некоторых товаров по-умолчанию 0, выводится цена минимальной категории, но сортировка работает не корректно).

Comment: поясните price_option

Comment: Извиняюсь. Я имел ввиду что при сортировке должна учитываться не цена товара, а цена товара+цена его опции(минимальная).